# Generic Function uses Array push causes error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In this code the type of array is already defined but Typescript fires an error for the array push, saying that:

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

```
type Characters = {
    letters: string[];
    numbers: number[];
}

const characters :Characters = {
    letters:  ['a', 'b',' c' ],
    numbers: [1,2,3],
}

type AddCharacter = <K extends keyof Characters, V extends Characters[K][number]>
(characterType:K, character:V) => void;

const addCharacter  :AddCharacter = (characterType, character) =>{
   characters[characterType].push(character) //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
}

addCharacter('letters', 'd') //ok
addCharacter('numbers', 4) //ok
addCharacter('letters', 4) //error as expected beacause 4 is not a string
addCharacter('numbers', 'd') //error as expected beacause d is not a number
addCharacter('words', 'test' )  //error as expected because 'words' is not a key of 'Characters'
```

I cannot figure out why it showing error since the type seem to be correct (got perfect type checking calling `addCharacter`).
How can I get rid of the error and getting it to work nicely with typescript?
Thanks for any help!
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwE4IMbAkgzlAvFAbwCgpSoAbCYDbALii2CQEsA7AcwG0BdAbhLKsArgFsARpiz1h4zD34BfIkVQB7VoyipEKdJKi14yNDRz5iZClVP0onAOQJ7AGij2xL%201q-dnA0jISdHYAjM4ATM4AzL5ESkSgkFAAggAmqUa6NHhQADwA0lAQAB4YrKk4ANYQIKoAZrA6JpKuAGpFpRDlOJnN2Jz53JyBmNwAfEQAFNrGekgAKuAQtPmuM1mYtK0AlHhjUABuqsyp-CrqmgjpvXOktGkZTbf40080i5Brb5i7uGMWpHWfSwnCBcw%20EG4ADowEIsHBXrMaLsAPQoiFuRgsDheZg4ViqYBQBBYLDMdisBBiShQYCqWlLNysCAHTD2OLKK6PJGYSb2SjUSQuKAAFlRKMwSFUSGJOBKkD0qSgEjQCDh0BFUDxUAJRIQDCYbHYRC5NxofIFpmF9lS9nFqkqJuu3yQfJG2GFYqgaIdTu5G1d9ndWGttvFkulso6CowSpVqDVWGgSu1uuJOtEQT9Zt59gA7tKKtaMIwvLtvRKkFKZSToxBFcr64noPnCyGtfjCenqiAoPU3DmPUA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert the following line into the body of `addCharacter`,

```
let x = characters[characterType][1]
```

You'll see that Typescript infers the type of `x` to be `string | number`, which implies that `characters[characterType]` is `string[] | number[]`.

That would explain why, if you inspect the type of the called `push` method, the `items` parameter has type `never[]`,

```
(method) Array<T>.push(items: never[]): number
```

because `T` is `string[] | number[]`, not just `string[]` or just `number[]`. This causes the type of `items` to be `never[]`, which in turn results in the error message you see.

You can fix the issue by changing `addCharacter` to:

```js
const addCharacter:AddCharacter = <K extends keyof Characters, V extends Characters[K][number]>(characterType: K, character: V) => {
    (characters[characterType] as V[]).push(character)
}
```

This forces the type of `characters[characterType]` to be the dynamically inferred type of `V` based on the type of `K`. I don't know why Typescript doesn't do this automatically. Perhaps a Typescript guru can explain. Or perhaps we should file a Typescript Issue.

Comment: In order to make it safe, TS just makes intersection `string & number`, this is why there is `never`

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick, thanks a ton for the detailed explaination

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine But static analysis should prove that `characters[characterType]` is of type `V[]`, no?

Comment: Thanks for the missing `(characters[characterType] as V[])`. What's funny is `characters[characterType][characters[characterType].length] = character` will be infered correctly :-/